# Multiple Ternary in C with comma?

Tags: c, obfuscation, deobfuscation

so I saw this code

```
b[2080];
main(j) {
  for (;;) {
    printf("\x1b[H");
    for (j = 1; j < 2080; j++) 
    b[j] = j < 2000 ? (b[j + 79] + b[j + 80] + b[j] + b[j - 1] + b[j + 81]) / 5 : rand() % 4 ? 0 : 512, j < 1840 ? putchar((j % 80) == 79 ? '\n' : " .:*#$H@" [b[j] >> 5]) : 0;
    usleep(20000);
  }
}
```

so I tried to rewrite it, why even divide 32?
The array got to declare as global else it won't work. any idea?
also why 512?
here is my attempt so far, any problem?

```
for (int j = 1; j < 2080; j++) 
            {
                if (j < 2000) {
                    b[j] = (b[j + 79] + b[j + 80] + b[j] + b[j - 1] + b[j + 81]) / 5;
                }
                else if (rand() % 4 != 0) { // Generate random integers in range 0 to 4
                          b[j] = 0;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         b[j] = 512;
                     }
                   
                }
            }
```

Comment: In C of course you can do ```a = 1, b = 2``` and the comma is just evaluated from left to right, here it almost functions as a semicolon. So I think the assignment is evaluated first and then the stuff following on the comma, basically everything from ```j < 1840 ... ;``` is evaluated regardless and in your code should be put outside and after the if statement.

Comment: I think you can replace the comma with a semi and put braces around it to keep those now two statements inside the loop and the meaning will be the same.

Comment: It you love frustrating days, weeks or months of debugging - yes, this kind of code is perfect for the purpose#

Comment: This kind of question can invariably be answered by a simple look at the operator precedence table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence . This lists the ternary operator `?:` as level 16 (along with all the assignment operators), and the comma operator at the lowest precedence level 17. As such, the `,` separates the first assignement `b[j] = j < 2000 ? ...` from the conditional output `j < 1840 ? putchar(...`. Consequently, the `>>` sees the new value written by the part before the comma.

Comment: @P__J__ Reverse engineering such code is an excellent exercise for getting a more precise understanding of the language, though. For example, you can only correctly decipher `11["Hello World!\n"]` once you have understood how the array subscript operator `[]` is actually defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the functionally equivalent code with the ternary operators converted into `if/else` statements:

```
            if (j < 2000) {
                b[j] = (b[j + 79] + b[j + 80] + b[j] + b[j - 1] + b[j + 81]) / 5;
            } else if (rand() % 4) {
                b[j] = 0;
            } else {
                b[j] = 512;
            }
            if (j < 1840) {
                if ((j % 80) == 79) {
                    putchar('\n');
                } else {
                    putchar(" .:*#$H@"[b[j] / 32]);
                }
            }
```

As for the question of what does the right shift `>> 5` do, it divides by 32 (2<sup>5</sup>), and then indexes the array `" .:*#$H@"` with that divided value.

**edit**: As for why the array is global, it's probably just to get it initialised to zero without extra code (the whole thing seems to be written as short as possible, e.g., using implicit `int` types and `j` from the argument).

Note that there is an access out of bounds bug in the (original) code: `b[j + 81]` can be accessed when `j` is `1999` (since that is `< 2000`), but `1999 + 81 == 2080`, and `b[2080]` is out of bounds. You can replace the array with a local `int b[2081] = { 0 };` but it changes the output slightly while fixing the bug.

Comment: thank you so much, awesome, in the end there is a  : 0; that I think u left out after putchar, what do that 0 do?

Comment: I think the zero is there to do nothing in the "else" case of the ternary operator.

Comment: As for the magic numbers, it seems that it assumes the screen to be 80×25 characters, `80 * 25 == 2000`, then one extra row to make it `2080` without having to treat the last row as a special case. The `-1`, `+1`, `+79`, `+80`, `+81` are the adjacent characters on the same and next row. The iteration starts at `j = 1` so the `b[j - 1]` is not out of bounds, unlike the `b[j + 81]` in the original. And the `1840` is two rows short of the full screen, probably to avoid scrolling.

Comment: any idea on why it's 512?

Comment: @GinMay The 512 is randomly assigned with an approx 1/4 chance to cells in the invisible bottom row. This is really the only way high numbers come into the visible area, since everything else is either zero or the average of 5 adjacent cells. There are 8 different characters and the index is the cell's value divided by 32, so the values of visible cells should be less than 8×32=256 but to see the last character they should be at least 7×32=224. 512 is probably chosen as large enough a seed to occasionally propagate such high values upwards (past the two invisible rows).

Comment: (Note that there is also an out of bounds access to the string that happens when the random number generator happens to produce streaks of 512s, so the choice is not really mathematically sound. i.e., probably just chosen as something that seems to work in practice. The fix for this would be to cap the result of the division before indexing.)